# Customize alert title in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, dialog, alert, chromium

I have an Chrome extension, that displays messages using the alert() call. The default behaviour display the title as "The extension at  says: ...". Can't this be changed to something meaningful? I tried using the Rich Notification API but has limits on the size of the text that gets displayed in the box.

I am able to this in firefox using:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Overlay_Extensions/XUL_School/Adding_windows_and_dialogs#Alert

But can't find something similar for Chrome.

Comment: From the background page?

Comment: @DanielHerr yes from the background page.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't for safety reasons. Around the web, you can find some modal dialogs to emulate it but I think the result won't be the same that you expect.